# Extract data in XML file with bash

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed, grep

I need help extracting an XML string from file like this:

```html
<line>
<Start_Time>2016-May-18 17.06.17.504</Start_Time>
<Domain>pciereg062</Domain>
<Injected_tags>
 before xml started ; AUTOMATIC-REPRODUCTION-stopped on barrier ;
</Injected_tags>
</line>

<line>
<Start_Time>2016-May-18 17.08.53.585</Start_Time>
<Domain>adv191</Domain>
<Injected_tags>port-num-0 ; port-num-0 actual-FW-14.16.0234 ;
</Injected_tags>
</line>
```

I want to extract the domain name which is in injected_tags (which will come always after domain) string stopped on barrier.

Is there a simple bash utility to do this (grep, awk, sed)?

From the example above, the output should be  `pciereg062` and not `adv191`.

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Comment: See: [Using xmlstarlet, how do I change the value of an element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35636357/3776858)

Comment: While it's quick, dirty, bad and shooting-in-your-leg solution, it should work as long as your XML input structure remains the same: `grep -B 2 'stopped on barrier' input.xml | grep -Po '(?<=<Domain>).*(?=</Domain>)'`.
You really should look into some XML parser like Cyrus suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='</[^>]+>' -F'[<>]' '{m[$2]=$3} $2=="Injected_tags" && /stopped on barrier/{print m["Domain"]}' file
pciereg062
```