# Editing xml from script

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell

I need to run a user-data script in an *ec2-instance* that changes an XML in a folder.

I have an XML like this one in a path in the *ec2*:

```xml
<Root>
    <Properties>
       <Property>
          <Name>myProp</Name>
          <Value>old_value</Value>
       </Property>
       <Property>
          <Name>anotherProp</Name>
          <Value>other_value</Value>
       </Property>
    </Propierties>
</Root>
```

I want to change *old_value* into *new_value*. But just that one, not *other_value*.

How can I do this?

I've tried a *powershell* script but I don't know how to run it to test it:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
$path = '/home/wowza/conf/Server.xml'

$new_value = 'new_value'

$xml = [xml](Get-Content $path)

$xml.Data.Course.Subject

$property = $xml.Root.Server.Properties.Property | where {$_.Name -eq 'myProp'}
$property.Value = $new_value

$xml.Save($path)
```

Please if you send me a script don't forget to include how to run it to test it, the interpreter for the #! line and what things to install. 
Thank you!

Comment: This might help: [Using xmlstarlet, how do I change the value of an element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35636357/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will allow you to set the new_value for the targeted field even if you don't know what the old_value is:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i -e '/<Name>myProp<\/Name>/,/<Value>/s/^\s*<Value>.*$/<Value>new_value<\/Value>/' /folder/xml-file
```

The only caveat here is that the script will strip white space indentations from the line to be changed, but that is only a visual thing that does not affect the code result; you can add the indentation spaces you need afterwards with another sed command, if that is important to you.

Comment: Do you know how I could make it independent of the old_value text? I mean, to get it changed even if old_value is different?

Comment: The code above already does that - it will change the value of the targeted field regardless of what the old_value is (and you do not need to refer to the old_value anywhere). Just change the new_value on the code above to whatever you want to update the value to.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i '/<Name>myProp<\/Name>/,/<Value>old_value<\/Value>/s/old_value/new_value/' file.xml
```

Output to file file.xml:

```
<Root>
    <Properties>
       <Property>
          <Name>myProp</Name>
          <Value>new_value</Value>
       </Property>
       <Property>
          <Name>anotherProp</Name>
          <Value>other_value</Value>
       </Property>
    </Propierties>
</Root>
```

Comment: This works perfectly!!!!! Thank you.   Do you know how I could make it independent of the old_value text? I mean, to get it changed even if old_value is different?

Comment: Try this: `sed -i '/<Name>myProp<\/Name>/,/<Value>/s/<Value>[^<]*/<Value>new_value/' file.xml` or `sed -E '/<Name>myProp<\/Name>/,/<Value>/s/(<Value>).*(<\/Value>)/\1new_value\2/' file.xml`